# Multiple positive lookahead assertions failing to match in .NET regex

Tags: .net, regex, office365

I am trying to create a mail flow rule in O365 which will need to match specific elements from the `Authentication-Results` header. Here is a redacted sample header:

```
Authentication-Results: spf=pass (sender IP is 12.34.56.78) smtp.mailfrom=relayprovider.net; dkim=pass (signature was verified) header.d=replayprovider.net;dmarc=none action=none header.from=example.com;compauth=fail reason=001
```

I need to match the rule when ALL of these specific substrings are present:
`dkim=pass`
`spf=pass`
`header.d=relayprovider.net`
`header.from=example.com`

In other words, when we receive an email from Example.com's bulk mailer (relayprovider.net) and that email passes dkim and spf checks.

O365 mail flow rules only allow a single condition on the headers and only `OR` statements for for each match condition, I was planning to use a regular expression to match the header, using positive lookahead assertions to match the header only if all of the substrings are present. Here is my Regex:

`(?=dkim=pass)(?=spf=pass)(?=header.from=example.com)(?=header.d=relayprovider.net)`

When I try testing this in a supposedly .NET compliant Regex tester against the sample header above, I get no match. If I use only a single assertion like `(?=dkim=pass)` or `(?=spf=pass)`, I get a match, but when I combine them it doesn't match.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?=dkim=pass)` requires `dkim=pass` to immediately follow previous match. As all the other your lookaheads, which are mutually exclusive.

You need to use

```
^(?=.*dkim=pass)(?=.*spf=pass)(?=.*header\.from=example.com)(?=.*header\.d=relayprovider.net)
```

to check anywhere inside string.

Also, I've escaped your dots, just in case.

Comment: To simplify a bit I tried just `^(?=.*spf=pass)(?=.*dkim=pass)$` against the test string and got no match. If I do just `^(?=.*spf=pass)$` I get a match.

Comment: EDIT: what ultimately worked is `^.*(?=.*spf=pass)(?=.*dkim=pass).*$`. Marking this as the correct answer.

Comment: @CharliePatton, `^(?=.*spf=pass)(?=.*dkim=pass)$` is impossible to match: `(?=.*spf=pass)` requires `spf=pass` to be present, but doesn't actually matches anything. So your regex requires a bunch of strings to be present, but later boils down to `^$` - empty string. You can see that my answer lacks `$` at the end: exactly for this reason.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and I now see what you mean.